# Randomly Generate Multiple Files From Directory with PHP

Tags: php, html, image, loading, random

I am building a website where people can go and upload images, gifs, and videos. On the home page, I want to list files at random from the upload directory.

```
<article class="item thumb" data-width="384">
    <h2><?php echo $file_title;?></h2>
    <a href="<?php echo $randomImage ?>"><img src="<?php echo $randomImage ?>" alt=""></a>
</article>

<article class="item thumb" data-width="274">
    <h2><?php echo $file_title;?></h2>
    <a href="<?php echo $randomImage ?>"><img src="<?php echo $randomImage ?>" alt=""></a>
</article>
```

And it does that for a total of five times. $randomImage is generated from the code:

```
<?php
   $imagesDir = 'uploads/';
   $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
   $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
   $file_title = $randomImage;
?>
```

I want to be able to add a feature to where as the user scrolls down, more and more of these articles containing images show up, each containing a random but not previously shown file. How can I display files at random without having to manually enter unique variables?

P.S. Right now I do not have any files stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Remove randomly selected image from `$images` before you select another.

loop for 5 images

```
<?php
// get all files

$imagesDir = 'uploads/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$imagesCount = count($images);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $imagesCount ; $i++) {

    // select image 

    $randomIndex = array_rand($images); // select image index

    $file_title = $randomImage = $images[$randomIndex]; // use selected image

    unset($images[$randomIndex]); // remove selected image
    // print_r($images); // you can see what left in $images

    // show image

    ?>
    <article class="item thumb">
        <h2><?php echo $file_title;?></h2>
        <a href="<?php echo $randomImage ?>"><img src="<?php echo $randomImage ?>" alt=""></a>
    </article>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I used this code and it loads the same image at each block. What variable should I used when I call: <img src="<?php echo $randomImage ?>" alt=""> instead of $randomimage?

Comment: You have to get new `$randomImage` before each block. See new code in my answer.

Comment: Perfect! Instead of looping for only 5 images, I need it to continue loading images as more and more blocks are loaded. There is going to be a feature that when a user scrolls over, more content boxes will appear. How can I set this code up to loop forever and continue insuring the same image isn't loaded twice?

Comment: Using `count($images)` you can get all images - see code above - but it give you all images at once. If you need to load more blocks when user scroll you need JavaScript + Ajax and PHP will have to remember `$images` in file. Or you could send `$images` to javascript and do all the job in javascript (select random image and show next block)